# Передача функции из одной формы в другую (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с данной проблемой при передачи функции из одной формы в другую.
Как её решить?

**Login:**

```
private MainClient OnConnect;
private MainClient OnDataReceived;
private MainClient OnServerDisconnect;
public Login(MainClient OnConnect, MainClient OnDataReceived, MainClient OnServerDisconnect)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.OnConnect = OnConnect;
    this.OnDataReceived = OnDataReceived;
    this.OnServerDisconnect = OnServerDisconnect;
}

private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    MainClient._client = new Sock.Client { BufferSize = 1048576 };
    MainClient._client.OnConnect += OnConnect; //Problem
    MainClient._client.OnDataReceived += OnDataReceived; //Problem
    MainClient._client.OnServerDisconnect += OnServerDisconnect; //Problem
    ...
}
```

**Main:**

```
...
public static Sock.Client _client = new Sock.Client();
public static ClientInfo _clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
...
private void runLoginScreen()
{
    Application.Run(new Login(this, this, this));
}
```

Проблема `Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "Project_Name.Main" в "Sock.Client.ServerDisconnectedEventHanlder".` Помечена в коде как "**Problem**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К событиям `Sock.Client.OnConnect`, `Sock.Client.OnDataReceived` и `Sock.Client.OnServerDisconnect` нужно подписывать методы с соответствующими сигнатурами, а не инстансы класса `MainClient`.

Посмотрите, как описано событие `Sock.Client.OnConnect`, какие у него параметры. Заведите в классе `MainClient` метод (название - неважно, например, `ConnectHandler`) с такими же параметрами. Тогда Вы сможете написать:

```
private MainClient mainClient;
public Login(MainClient aMainClient)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.mainClient = aMainClient;
}

private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    MainClient._client = new Sock.Client { BufferSize = 1048576 };
    MainClient._client.OnConnect += mainClient.ConnectHandler; //No problem
    ...
```

Аналогично - для `OnDataReceived` и `OnServerDisconnect`.

Только почему у Вас обработчики событий объекта, который принадлежит классу `MainClient`, назначает `Login`?

Comment: Более детальный ответ пожалуйста. Как это сделать?

Comment: Спасибо. Не только  помогли, но и уменьшили код)
Я что-то не догадаться так сделать...